# How to avoid 'too many requests' warning in Selenium after multiple attempts?

Tags: php, html, selenium-webdriver

I did too many code attempts in selenium and it gave warning.

How can I make code attempts multiple times without warning? As an example up to 10000 attempts.

This is my code:

```py
 for i in range(1, 100000):
    number = '{:06}'.format(i)
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/input")
    time.sleep(1)
    input_element.clear()
    input_element.send_keys(number)
    input_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    try:
          # Sonuç elementinin id'sini buraya yazın
        result_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"personal-information\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/input")
        if result_element.text == 'Beklenen Sonuç':
                print(
                    f"Girilen değer: {number}, Beklenen sonuç bulundu: {result_element.text}")
                found = True
                break  # Sonucu bulduktan sonra döngüyü kırar
        else:
                print(f"Girilen değer: {number}, Geçersiz sonuç: {result_element.text}")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f"Sonuç bulunamadı: {number}")
```

Comment: Just slow it down.